# How can I receive UDP data in Android?

Tags: java, android

I send data from a PC to Android. But I can't receive the data using UDP in Android. How to receive data by using UDP in Android? How can I see the received data on the android-display? Can anyone help me?

Code is here:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  EditText textOut;
  EditText port;
  int UDP_SERVER_PORT = 8255;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.main);
    try {
      int port = UDP_SERVER_PORT;
      Log.d("UDP", "Connecting..");
      DatagramSocket clientsocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
      byte[] receivebuf = new byte[1024];
      DatagramPacket receivepacket =
        new DatagramPacket(receivebuf,receivebuf.length);
      clientsocket.receive(receivepacket);
      String modifiedSentence = new String(receivepacket.getData());
      System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);
      clientsocket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("UDP", "C: Error", e);
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For looking the data recevied let us suppose data is converted to string and then you need a view to set its value equal to data recevied . Does it make sense to you .

Comment: Its simple initialize a textview like below TextView viewToShow = new TextView(context); viewtoShow.settext(//string recevied from socket);

Comment: String receivestring=new String(receivepacket.getData());           
textview.setText(" Received String "+receivestring);

Comment: THis findviewbyid will be used only if you are using xml resource to inflate your view like setContentView(R.layout.//xmllayoutfilename); I have told you how to dynamically add textview without using setContentView(R.layout.//xmllayoutfilename); In my example case you have add setContentView(//textviewreference);

Comment: TextView viewToShow = new TextView(this); viewToShow.setText(" Received String "+receivestring); i can see data in logcat.but not on the display..

Comment: TextView viewToShow = new TextView(this);  setContentView(R.layout.//xmllayoutfilename);  viewToShow.setText(" Received String "+receivestring);  Please do in this sequence